# Accept which array method by caller in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

**Background:**

The only difference between the following functions is:

- `createGrid` uses `map` (taking a callback returning type `T`) and returns `T[][]`
- `visitGridCoordinates` uses `forEach` (taking a callback returning type `void`) and returns `void`.

```
const createGrid = <T>(width: number, height: number, callback: (x: number, y:number) => T) =>
  Array
    .from(Array(width).keys())
    .map(
      (x: number) => Array
        .from(Array(height).keys())
        .map((y: number) => callback(x, y))
    );

const visitGridCoordinates = (width: number, height: number, callback: (x: number, y:number) => void) =>
  Array
    .from(Array(width).keys())
    .forEach(
      (x: number) => Array
        .from(Array(height).keys())
        .forEach((y: number) => callback(x, y);)
    );
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to create a wrapper function over these that takes which method to use as an argument? I tried several things but kept running into problems.

```
const createGrid = verbGrid<string>(Array.prototype.map); // or ('map') alternately
const visitGridCoordinates = verbGrid(Array.prototype.forEach); // or ('forEach') alternately

const verbGrid = ???
```

I tried writing such a function, then used "infer parameter types from usages" and the result *almost* works:

```
const verbGrid = <U>(arrayMethod: (callbackfn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void) => (
  width: number,
  height: number,
  callback: ((x: number, y:number) => U) | ((x: number, y:number) => boolean)
) => {
  const result: void | U[][] = arrayMethod.call(
    Array.from(Array(width).keys()),
    (x: number) => arrayMethod.call(
      Array.from(Array(height).keys()),
      (y: number) => callback(x, y)
    )
  )
  return result;
};
```

But when I try to use `createGrid` its return type is always only `void`. And of course it is, because the type of `arrayMethod` says it returns `void`. When I try using unioned types for the entire type descriptor or just for the return value, various different errors occur.

I played around with using `varof` as in `varof Array<number>["map"] | varof Array<number>["forEach"]` to get more explicit with the types and avoid having to re-describe both method types. However I still had no luck (and I notice the `map` version doesn't specify `U` anywhere and I don't know how to do that).

Is this even possible, and if so, do you mind helping me understand where I'm going wrong?

Various results I've had:

- The result of `verbGrid` being type `unknown`.
- No errors in `verbGrid` but being unable to assign the result to a variable of type `U[][]` at the call site.
- Passing in `'map'` and `'forEach'` as strings and using them as `[method]` (instead of doing `method.call`).

I tried to simplify things a little like so:

```
type ValueReturning = <T, U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[];
type VoidReturning = <T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void, thisArg?: any) => void;

class Enumerable {
  static range(start: number, count: number) {
    return Array.from(Array(count).keys()).map(index => start + index);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work at all ("Type 'ValueReturning' is not generic"):

```
const verbGrid = <U>(arrayMethod: ValueReturning<number, U> | VoidReturning<number>) => (
```

Appreciate any guidance.

*Note: I am new to TypeScript but not new to Generics (from C#).*

*Addendum*

In case it helps, here are the call sites to these two functions.

```
this._grid = createGrid(width, height, (x: number, y: number) => {
  const cell = new Cell<string>(x, y);
  this._cells.add(cell);
  return cell;
});
visitGridCoordinates(width, height, (x, y) => {
  getNeighborCoordinates(width, height, x, y)
    .forEach(([neighborX, neighborY]) => {
      this.grid[x][y].neighbors.add(this._grid[neighborX][neighborY]);
    });
});
```

It's fine to suggest alternate methods for achieving the same goal, but I really was more interested in learning TypeScript better than I am in fixing this code to be perfectly optimal. (I spent a couple of hours creating a Boggle/Wordament solver last night—it works great and was fun to build.)

Comment: `forEach()` is unbreakable in JS, returning `false` doesn't do anything

Comment: @jcalz I see you are right. It was an eslint warning made me think that `Array.forEach` did have an early termination. But now when I try it, there's nothing there. Quite puzzling!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some annoying difficulties with this, like you did. One type function that I found useful is this:

```
type ArrayUnlessVoid<T> = T extends void ? void : Array<T>;
```

It's a conditional type that turns `T` into `T[]` unless `T` is `void`, in which case it's just `void`.   We might want this because it unifies what `map()` and `forEach()` do: they each take a callback that returns a `T` and returns an `ArrayUnlessVoid<T>`.

Okay, here is the typing for `verbGrid()`:

```
const verbGrid =
    <R, O>(arrayMethod: (
        callbackfn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => R,
        thisArg?: any
    ) => O) =>
        (width: number, height: number, callback: ((x: number, y: number) => R)) => {

            const outerArrayMethod = arrayMethod as any as (
                callbackfn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => O,
                thisArg?: any
            ) => ArrayUnlessVoid<O>;

            const result = outerArrayMethod.call(
                Array.from(Array(width).keys()),
                (x: number) => arrayMethod.call(
                    Array.from(Array(height).keys()),
                    (y: number) => callback(x, y)
                ));

            return result;
        }
```

Blecch.  It would be nice if `verbGrid` could take something that turns a callback-returning-`T` into an `ArrayUnlessVoid<T>` and returns an `ArrayUnlessVoid<ArrayUnlessVoid<T>>`.  But the compiler can't really see that `Array.prototype.map()` matches the former definition.  So I add a new type parameter `O` to take the place of `ArrayUnlessVoid<T>` and return `ArrayUnlessVoid<O>` instead.

It would also be nice if there were some easier way to describe the two different contexts in which you use `arrayMethod` in the implementation.  Instead I just give up and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to give the outer call to `arrayMethod` a different type signature.

Anyway, you can see that these work as advertised:

```
const createGrid = verbGrid(Array.prototype.map); 
// const createGrid: <U>(
//   width: number, height: number, callback: (x: number, y: number) => U
// ) => U[][]

const visitGridCoordinates = verbGrid(Array.prototype.forEach); 
// const visitGridCoordinates: (
//   width: number, height: number, 
//   callback: (x: number, y: number) => void
// ) => void
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAqgOwDYQM7YGoD2AlgCYA8AKgHxQC8UFUEAHsBGidlAG7ElQB+HnygAuWAmSUqAbgCwAKEUBjAmmzAeEOACMA4nFJ1FUU1DIAlADRQA8lQAUiSSACyEYAAsCJcQ5NmgcqIGBg6iMoA1gBmaH7cIQCuEOKIaCA2RBws4miJALY62jbOSCCp6QDaALoAlHQ01gGBpl5E2PAA5gIVIM1Q9bQ0toNU-YEOAO6kXrkFRXA2nhBEnZ7Ac4XFUMGh4VF+DsybCzblUHlbcKNQFrU3AN6K4y2mquqaBIlscPBl7l4fHQoKVkADvPxEFw0iAQVx-ApXkizLswhEYnEoA4Ehhkr1Mtljhd5ttQecYTUbrYrC9ka1PO0uj0QelaS0bn9kOgsLhCKQyPZ5EpEXS3moNFA4DhEhhNPQvj9OW4PBCAHSohGi15K1XROAEfIOJVTGaeWqqyIQEDYBz3GkirVmI4nbQ3MngnzqkIYTWOpE6vUGo0uBzLVbrc2W6222r2v1IhznS4LG6o-aRI5nWps5H3IU5sxS4CJOBoSXS2VC5EAXygz2F7wlyiliDYBiM9G42n0hhIwbKqrA+uABFAkFV+UQYFqMjrCgA9POduLNM2IK2IO3fOYUI5piRZsSrksVmsNkfTjtvem-ETk9skyTrg0oCgbigajV643NNx2kRgC3ABhAgCDgEgsg3LhO27Ld+2QQdh1HcAIF1MCAFEIjNWdFEXZcPh4f9AN7ECwIgtAoL8fdD3vRYoDDM8XTotN0VvJiziYm5eFILi+HrIA)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that! I admit I am playing here as much as doing anything super useful. I'll update my question to show how I'm using the function. In the long run, it's probably better if I just keep it simple by making the two functions be separate. But I like to learn how to use my tools better. :)